# What does "$" in the line "i:= i - $24" on Delphi?

Tags: delphi

What does "`$`" in the line "`i:= i - $24`" on Delphi?
I rewrite code to C++. It's use in the simple of bass.dll.

```
// complete the WAV header
WaveStream.Position := 4;
i := WaveStream.Size - 8;
WaveStream.Write(i, 4);
i := i - $24;
WaveStream.Position := 40;
WaveStream.Write(i, 4);
WaveStream.Position := 0;
```

Comment: I removed the spurious C and C++ tags. This is a pure Delphi question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a prefix to declare the value '24' as a hexadecimal value instead of decimal. So the decimal value is 36.

It is equivalent to 0x24 in C++.

Comment: or 0x24 in C/C++/C# etc